# Visual C++: Parallel Patterns Library - How to cancel task returned by a factory method?

Tags: c++, ppl

According to the MSDN I can cancel a task as follows:

```
cancellation_token_source cts;
auto token = cts.get_token();

auto t = create_task([]
{
    bool moreToDo = true;
    while (moreToDo)
    {
        if (is_task_cancellation_requested())
        {
            cancel_current_task();
        }
        else 
        {
            moreToDo = do_work();
        }
    }
}, token);

cts.cancel();
```

But how can I cancel a task returned by a factory method like that:

```
service->get_me_results().then([]()
{
     // ...
});
```